# How to map string into object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following data string from a table and it looks like this:

The data format is correct, each row goes to a new line due to the amount of data.

```
const data = 
       "0 | john | doe | 
        US | Employed 
        1 | bob| dylan | 
        US | Unemployed "
```

How can I efficiently map data to the correct format? I want to output to an array of objects per row like below:

```
[{rowId: 0, name: "john", surname: "doe"}. {...}]
```

I initially tried to split by pipe it but it looked like this:

```
["0 ", " john ", " doe ", "US ", " Employed 1", " bob", " dylan ", "US ", " Unemployed"]
```

Comment: What format is the source data in? Like CSV?

Comment: Will every row have the same number of elements, regardless of line breaks, and are they strictly ordered? If so just iterate through your array after splitting and count out the elements.

Comment: @pilchard every row will have same number of columns and yes order will never change.

Comment: you can `trim` strings

Comment: @Bravo I have already done so. Just not sure how to map data to object array

Comment: If you've used trim, you did it wrong

Comment: Can you confirm that there are actually line breaks and not just wrapping on your display?

Comment: @pilchard they are line breaks

Comment: Alright, I'll leave my answer as is then.

Answer (score 2):

**Example below**

```js
const data =
  "0 | john | doe |   US | Employed  1 | bob| dylan |  US | Unemployed ";

const arr = data
  .split("|")
  .flatMap(el => el.split(" "))
  .filter(el => el !== "");

const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 5) {
  output.push({
    rowId: arr[i],
    name: arr[i + 1],
    surname: arr[i + 2],
    country: arr[i + 3],
    status: arr[i + 4],
  });
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You've conveniently removed the line breaks?

Comment: @pilchard, There is no line break in between if you look at ```data``` because OP use double quote for the data object.  Also, OP mention he used split("|") and get a array object from it.

Comment: That could easily be a typing issue and not reflective of the actual data. I would guess that there is a combination of wrap and line breaks at work, I've asked the OP to clarify.

Comment: @pilchard, OP mentioned ```split by pipe``` and get ```["0 ", " john ", " doe ", "US ", " Employed 1", " bob", " dylan ", "US ", " Unemployed"]``` That's why I think there is no line break

Comment: That is consistent with a line break at `Employed\n 1`

Comment: @pilchard, The array OP get should be ```["0 ", " john ", " doe ", "US ", " Employed\n1", " bob", " dylan ", "US ", " Unemployed"]``` instead of ```["0 ", " john ", " doe ", "US ", " Employed 1", " bob", " dylan ", "US ", " Unemployed"]```

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point, I'll edit mine on the same assumption

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every row will have same number of columns and order will never change

```js
// const data = `0 | john | doe | US | Employed | 1 | bob| dylan | US | Unemployed`; <= My assumption of data was incorrect.

const data = `0 | john | doe | US | Employed 1 | bob| dylan | US | Unemployed`;

const cleanedUp = data.split("|").flatMap(d => d.split(' ')).filter(d => d!== '');
console.log(cleanedUp);
const result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cleanedUp.length; i += 5) { // i+=5 can solve your problem
  result.push({
    rowId: cleanedUp[i],
    name: cleanedUp[i + 1],
    surname: cleanedUp[i + 2]
  })
}

console.log(result)
```

The for loop will consider `5` elements as one row. Assuming each row starts with a numeric value like 0,1,2.. and so on

Comment: I did try something like this but if you can see my split output the last column of the row does not end with | how can I know that it's the next row

Comment: Since you mentioned each row will have the same number of columns, after we do a split using `|`, the for loop will consider `5` elements as one row. Assuming each row starts with a numeric value like 0,1,2.. and so on

Comment: Also, the output of split in your post is incorrect as per the data you provided.

Comment: I see, I guess i += 5 will determine each row. Thank you

Comment: @DaveDave, please clarify your data format between each records such as```Employed | 1``` is there any ```|``` in between actually?

Comment: It's a new row, so there is no pipe between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using an external `chunk()` function to chunk the split data elements into the correct size arrays which are then passed to an `Employee()` constructor function to turn them into objects.

Initial splitting is done on `\n`, `\r` and `|` and the returned array trimmed and filtered for empty strings.

```js
const
  data =
    `0 | john | doe | 
  US | Employed 
  1| bob | dylan |
  US | Unemployed `,

  chunk = (arr, chunk) => {
    let i, res = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunk) {
      res.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunk));
    }
    return res
  },

  Employee = ([rowId, name, surname, country, status]) => ({ rowId, name, surname, country, status }),

  splitData = data
    .split(/[\r\n\|]/g)               //split by newlines/returns and pipe
    .map(s => s.trim())               // trim whitespace
    .filter(s => s !== ''),           // filter out empty strings

  chunkedData = chunk(splitData, 5),  // chunk into subarrays of length

  result = chunkedData.map(Employee); // map to object using constructor declared above

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively, given that your structure is fixed you could use a regex to capture each row, the proceed with splitting by `|` and object mapping.

This works regardless of whether you have line breaks or not.

```js
const
  data1 = `0 | john | doe | 
  US | Employed 
  1| bob | dylan |
  US | Unemployed `,

  data2 = "0 | john | doe | US | Employed  1 | bob | dylan |  US | Unemployed ",

  Employee = ([rowId, name, surname, country, status]) => ({ rowId, name, surname, country, status }),

  splitData = data => data
    .match(/(?:.+?[\s\n\r]*\|[\s\n\r]*){4}.+?[\s\n\r]+/gm)   // capture each row with regex
    .map(row => row.split('|').map(s => s.trim())),         // map each row, split and trim

  result1 = splitData(data1).map(Employee), // map to object using constructor declared above
  result2 = splitData(data2).map(Employee); // map to object using constructor declared above

console.log('Multiline: \n');
console.log(result1);

console.log('\nSingle line: \n');
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I can never understand regex without putting it in regex101! I do like the `Employee` constructor pattern. +1

Answer (score 0):

New answer:

If rows are split by newline after "enough" columns (5), use a regex to split:

```js
const data =
  `0 | john | doe | 
        US | Employed 
        1 | bob| dylan | 
        US | Unemployed `;

const asObjects = data.split(/((?:[^|]+\|){4}[^|]+)(?:\n)/)
  .filter(v => v) // remove empty strings
  .map(v => v.split('|').map(v => v.trim()))
  .map(row => ({
    rowId: row[0],
    name: row[1],
    surname: row[2]
  }))
console.log(asObjects)
```

Explanation: [`string.split()` will include in the result any capture groups (parenthesis) but will omit non-capturing groups `(?:x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result)
So keep the five columns  and the "|" between them - "x|x|x|x|x" - `(([^|]+\|){4}[^|]+)`
But ignore the inner group to avoid a duplicate: `((?:[^|]+\|){4}[^|]+)`
And ignore the newline separating - add a `(?:\n)`

---

Old answer - assumption doesn't apply:
Assuming correct data, with every entry is in a new line and the fields in consistent order separated by " | ":

```js
const asObjects = data.split('\n').map(rawRow => rawRow.split(' | ')).map(row => ({ rowId: row[0], name: row[1], surname: row[2] }))
```

Comment: every entry is not on a newline, the rows wrap (for some reason?)

Comment: Hi, you can also use SO code snippets. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355